# VB Playing random sounds wav files

Tags: vb.net, background, audio

How do i play random sounds in vb, i have 3 wave files that i want to play at random in the background while using my application?

here is how i am playing just one song.

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Public Sub PlayRandomTrack()

    Dim trackNum As Integer = CInt(Rnd() * 3 + 0.5)

    Select Case trackNum

        Case 1
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music1, AudioPlayMode.Background)

        Case 2
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music2, AudioPlayMode.Background)

        Case Else
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music3, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    End Select

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the right method:

```
Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
End Function

Public Function Play(Byval Num as integer)
if num = 1 then
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
return true
elseif num = 2 then
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
return true
end if
return false
End Function
```

use it in this way:

```
play(GetRandom(1,2))
```